# How to update a list of objects in a JSON document

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON document like this:

```
[
    {"type":"IC","v":88},
    {"type":"SC","v":"XXX"},
    {"type":"IC","v":33},
    {"type":"IC","v":99999}
]
```

and I want to replace the value of `"v"` in each object so the resulted JSON document is like this:

```
[
    {"type":"IC","v":111},
    {"type":"SC","v":"YYYYYY"},
    {"type":"IC","v":222},
    {"type":"IC","v":333}
]
```

I'm wondering if there are some APIs to call to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are APIs to do such a thing. Check [json.org/java](http://www.json.org/java/).

Comment: Your JSON is mapped by the JSON parser into some set of objects.  Some JSON parsers map to ordinary Lists and Maps, others use custom objects such as JSONObject and JSONArray.  If you study the JSON syntax at json.org (takes 5 minutes to learn) you will see you have above an array (List) of objects (Maps).  It's a simple matter to iterate through the array and update the objects, just as you'd change the value for a given key in a standard Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lib in java : gson-2.2.3.jar

Comment: The question is about "how to" do this, you only answered the "some APIs" bit in a minimal way.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the Json string using Jackson or Gson and go through that array of objects and change the values programatically.

Answer (score 0):

look [json library](http://www.json.org/java/)

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{types:[{'type':'IC','v':88}, {'type':'SC','v':'XXX'}]}");
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
      JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
      item.put("vv", YOUR_DATA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using Objects will make life easy for you, for this I suggest Gson to map your json to an array of objects and then deserialize them back to the plain json

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize http://www.json.org/java/ among many other APIs available. In this context your json String is essentially a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html). Each element of this array is a [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

You can iterate over this array and work through your individual object's key/value pairs to manipulate the data to your liking.

In the below example (assuming Java 7 for String based switch/case), I get your jsonarray from the String (or a stream depending on your application), I iterate over the individual objects to get a handle on the key/values.

I then manipulate based on the *selective criteria* that you have.

Thus:

```
        String jsonString = "[{\"type\":\"IC\",\"v\":88},{\"type\":\"SC\",\"v\":\"XXX\"},{\"type\":\"IC\",\"v\":33},{\"type\":\"IC\",\"v\":99999}]";

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        System.out.println("BEFORE --> " + array);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            if (array.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

                switch ((String) obj.get("type")) {
                case "IC":
                    if (i == 0)
                        obj.put("v", 88);
                    else if (i == 2)
                        obj.put("v", 222);
                    else if (i == 3)
                        obj.put("v", 333);
                    break;
                case "SC":
                    obj.put("v", "YYYY");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("AFTER --> " + array);
```

Would give;

```
BEFORE --> [{"v":88,"type":"IC"},{"v":"XXX","type":"SC"},{"v":33,"type":"IC"},{"v":99999,"type":"IC"}]
AFTER --> [{"v":88,"type":"IC"},{"v":"YYYY","type":"SC"},{"v":222,"type":"IC"},{"v":333,"type":"IC"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

json-lib has various methods to manipulate JSONArray